# Why did I pass this Triage Review Audit?

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-audits, triage

Today I came across my [first triage audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/6852622).  For [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27690134/downcasting-c-structs-in-swift).

I studied the question for a while, it seemed to fall under the **looks good** category (and the 6 up-votes seem to agree with me, but I will get to that in a moment)

However, I was very puzzled because at first when I entered into the triage review it showed the question of having two down-votes.  I wish I had a screen shot of that but it seems I cannot reproduce that.

I wanted to mark it as **looks good** but the two down-votes made me question my judgement.  I eventually marked it as **should be improved** because the whole situation seemed odd.  Then of course I was told that it was a review, however, that I **passed**.  The question then updated to show the proper *6 up-votes*.

I don't quite understand why the system "passed" me if the question actually contains 6 up-votes.  If it was trying to "trick" me into marking it as **should be improved** because of the two fake down votes I think I actually should have failed the audit because I fell to the temptation.

1. Is this intended of the triage review audits (having false down-votes to trick you into marking it as "Should be Improved")?
2. Why did I pass when clearly the question is answerable and did not need improvement?

Comment: @bluet Yeah I completely agree now.  There is no justifiable reason for _Should Be Improved_ so I agree I shouldn't have passed this audit.  Perhaps I will rephrase this question to just reflect on "Why did I pass"

Comment: I would say "why did you pass" is a good question, but "why is it lying and showing downvotes that don't exist" is also a good question...

Comment: @neminem No.  That's actually fairly sensible.  If you make it look like a known-good post has downvotes, the reader should have the good sense to not mark it as bad just because of its score.  Likewise, they shouldn't be able to know that a post is a known-good audit just by seeing a lot of upvotes.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to just not show votes, then? (That is, show 0 votes, not change the UI to make it obvious that it was an audit.) Blatant lying doesn't seem right.

Comment: @neminem Then you'd know that every post without votes shown was an audit.

Comment: @Servy Or just that nobody had voted on it yet?

Comment: @neminem Showing a score of `0` is radically different from not showing the number of votes at all.  If you change it so that it always shows a score of 0 then you're still lying just as much as if you show a -2; either way the score shown isn't the real score.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Should be improved" responses are a bit tricky, in that folks tend to *think* they're appropriate for both good and bad questions. That's not really true - no one's going to be improving spam or blatantly off-topic questions, and there are plenty of questions that could benefit from but don't have a pressing *need* for improvement either.

So we're playing around with the criteria a bit right now. Should be Improved won't always fail, but it won't always pass either. If you know a post is unsalvageable, you should choose that option; similarly, if you know it's decent, you should say that.

The score was a rather unnecessary red herring here; unlike most other review queues, the bulk of the posts in Triage score 0 - so using the actual score of an audit isn't appropriate, but neither is throwing a random score on them. Therefore, Geoff made a change to fix these audit scores at 0, regardless of the actual score of the post.

Comment: Hm. Well, fixing at 0 isn't that bad an idea, but a slight chance for a single random vote in either direction would add to the realism...